# Setting Config?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

I need to change the destination in grunt copy in a loop.

I can do this via:

```
grunt.config.set('copy.files.dest', 'public/'+[i]);
```

Then run:

```
grunt.task.run('copy');
```

But the last dest set in the loop applies for all tasks.

How can I apply a separate dest for each task run in the loop?

Answer (score 1):

I provide to you only a pseudo code and idea how I was solved that kind of issue if I had to run some task in loop, maybe it can help to solve your issue. Create a task which will take a parameter:

```
module.exports = function(grunt){

    grunt.registerTask('myTask', 'Task description', function(dest){

        grunt.config.set('copy.files.dest', dest);
        grunt.task.run(['task list which uses parameter from copy.files.dest']);

    });

    return{
        tasks: {}
    };
};
```

This task will be called in you gruntfile in loop:

```
grunt.registerTask('myTask2', 'task description', function(){
    var params = ['/path/to/destination', 'second/path/to/dest'];

    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
        grunt.task.run('myTask1:' + params[i]);
    }
});
```

Comment: Good idea for setting params but not all tasks take params (such as copy) and it's not really answering the question.

Comment: I do not see your structure but if you collect all your task which need some kind of dynamically changing grunt config into one task, and you will run this one task in a loop and every task wil take care about which parameter will use then it can work. By the way there is also an grunt plugin which tries to solve that kind of issue: https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-galvanize

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've upvoted but as it's not the answer I can't accept. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You are welcome. Maybe I do not understand well what you want to achieve. I will follow this question for the answer.